# В чем здесь ошибка?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    int a = 2, b = 5;
    int* p1, * p2 = &b;
    *p1 = 10;
    cout << *p1 - *p2;
}
```

Comment: Куда вы пишите? `*p1 = 10;`

Comment: `int* p1 = new int; p1 = 10;`

Answer (score 6):

Использование неинициализированной корректным значением адреса в памяти переменной `p1`...